# Gaussian bluring differentiable by X and Y

Tags: image-processing, gaussian

Help me get the 3 * 3 matrix of coefficients of the Gaussian filter, differentiable by X and Y.

Is it just

```
 0 0 0
-1 0 1
 0 0 0
```

or not?

Answer (score 0):

You may use this 3x3 mask to compute the horizontal and vertical first derivatives:
[image]

Wolfram|Alpha also knows about that:

[http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=GaussianMatrix[1%2C{0%2C1}]](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=GaussianMatrix%5B1,%7B0,1%7D%5D)

Transpose to get the mask corresponding to the vertical first derivative.